# Inventory management database: definition vs. instances

Tags: mysql, design-patterns, database-design

At our company we are trying to implement a stock management system which suits our needs.

We have several parts to produce a product (sub-assembly, end product): `tpart`, so this is can be an atomic part, a sub-assembly or a final product. The sub-assemblies and final products are defined by `tbom` (bill of materials): this is the definition side.

Now for the instance side: each added part or part which leaves our company is stored in `ttransaction`. Let's say ten bolts are ordered at a supplier and delivered at our company, then we add a transaction '+10' with tpart_id of those bolts. Same idea for our end product which is manufactured at our company, we will create a '+1' transaction to identify the end product. If the end product is being shipped to the customer, a '-1' transaction is added. An end product is identified by a serial number.

The issue is that we want to be able to create a detailed history of an instance of a certain part. Some parts can have defects which are then returned for repair, after which they can leave the company again for the same or even a different customer. If possible we would also like to know which parts of a product were replaced during the repair.

Our (temporary, partially) database model looks like this:

[image]

`ttransaction_info` could possibly be omitted I think, `ttransaction_info_has_tpart` would then contain info on what parts were changed/repaired.

When `ttransaction` is huge (a lot of rows), will quering the table and performing inserts still be fast enough? I believe a lot of data will be retrieved from this table and I already have a couple of indexes there.

An alternative I was thinking about is have an `tinstance` table (separate from `ttransaction`) and a `thistory` table which references tinstance entries.

Is this the right way to implement?
I'm not sure which direction I should be heading, so if someone could shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're serious about this application, I would definitely recommend reading a data model pattern book, such as Hay's Enterprise Model Patterns. Highly rated on Amazon. Cheap on Safari. Vol 2 of Silverston's Data Model Resource Book covers MRP.

You are on the right track that you need to worry about definitions and instances.

Generally, the definition/specification is called a Product (or a Good), and the instance is called an Asset. A Product is "composed" of other Products.

There are a few kinds of Assets, Discrete Assets (like a car, with a serial number), Inventory Assets (like bolts, whose count you want but don't care about individual bolts), and Lot Assets.

"Transaction" is too vague a term here. I would suggest "Delivery" as a more specific term. The abstract type would be "Movement" and there are a few to worry about:

A shipment is what is supposed to happen and a delivery is what did happen.

(inbound) vendor shipment/delivery
(outbound) vendor return shipment/delivery
(outbound) customer shipment/delivery
(inbound) customer return shipment/delivery
internal shipment/delivery

A few hundred movements per product shouldn't be a problem with good indexing.